# Daylight Saving time from DB2

Tags: datetime, timezone, db2, dst, datetimeoffset

How can I know if the server where DB2 is running is configured with DST?

`CURRENT TIMEZONE` special register gives me the difference between UTC and the timestamp, but that difference can change (Summer/winter). Finally, I am not sure in which timezone the server is configured.

Let's suppose Paris is at +1 GMT. In summer, the CURRENT TIMEZONE is 20000, because DST is active, that means 2 hours. In winter, the CURRENT TIMEZONE INDICATES 10000, that corresponds exactly to the +1 GMT.

I would like to retrieve the name of the current timezone, and I could do that by matching the names and values of the timezone (stored in a table or inside a function), with the CURRENT TIMEZONE register and **DST**.

But how can I get the DST?

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone

Comment: The DB2 instance obtains the time and locale information, including the DST status, from the operating system, so you'd basically need to know the value of the `TZ` environment variable for the instance process.

Comment: But how from DB2? I was thinking about a external routine.

Comment: If the server's DBAs haven't provided a function, I suspect that you'll have to create one. Do you have a specific use case that could be discussed? The relationship between client and server seems relevant.

Comment: An external routine is probably the way to go. Here is an old article describing a related problem, perhaps you can make something out of that: `http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0407munteanu/`

Comment: ...and this is one of the reasons a common recommendation is to make the db (and perhaps the entire server) use UTC/GMT - no DST, no offset, no strange lengths of days, nada.  "Local Time" is usually a display/presentation issue for logged events (when a timestamp is to be used), not a domain issue.  Plus, it also saves you from one huge headache - doing any translation after changes to when DST occurs is terrible, you'd have to store when rule changes occur, and perform the math on the stored values.  Much better to perform it on the incoming parameters, and use an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> I would like to retrieve the name of the current timezone, and I could do that by matching the names and values of the timezone (stored in a table or inside a function), with the CURRENT TIMEZONE register and DST.

That is incorrect.  Any list that has a time zone offset mapped to a time zone name or identifier is bound to be full of errors, even if it has a flag for if DST is supported or not.

The problem is that many different time zones use the same offset and use DST, but enter and exit DST at different dates and/or different times.  Time zones also undergo changes to their rules for what offsets they follow (such as [Samoa did in 2011](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/samoa-dateline.html)), or for when DST starts and stops (such as [the USA did in 2007](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/us-daylight-saving-extended.html)).  And in some cases, DST can be permanently set on or off (such as Russia [did in 2011](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-winter-time.html) and is undoing [this year](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-abandons-permanent-summer-time.html)).

If you are just wanting to know whether the time zone where your database server is running is in DST or not - you can check the UTC offsets for Jan 1st and Jul 1st.  If they are the same, then the time zone doesn't use DST.  If they are different, then check the offset for the current time and see which it aligns with.  If it's the larger offset, then DST is in effect.  If it's the smaller offset then DST is not in effect.

*Disclaimer: I am assuming DB2 has a function to get the offset for a particular date. I have not verified that and have little knowledge of DB2 itself.*